# Как сделать "бесконечный цикл"? С#

Tags: c#

У меня при нажатии на кнопку запускается таймер, мне нужно выполнить определенную функцию после того, как таймер заканчивает свою работу (Не в теле самого таймера)
У меня была идея, сделать цикл, который будет проверять работу таймера, но как сделать так, чтобы он проверял его до того момента, пока тот не будет выключен? 
Или есть другие идеи к этой теме?

Comment: Что означает «в теле таймера»? Подпишитесь на события от таймера и в них делайте то, что вам нужно.

Comment: А почему нельзя просто в конце выполнения таймера вызвать нужную функцию? покажите пример кода, пока что это гадание на чайной гуще.

Comment: Код в таймере:
            TestText(Text); 
            timer1.Enabled = false;
Процедура не успевает завершить свою работу, из-за чего не выключается таймер, а таймер возобновляет цикл, т.е еще раз запускает процедуру

Comment: @Varagian, а если поменять местами команды: `timer1.Stop(); TestText(Text);` ?

Comment: Так работает намного лучше)))
Благодарствую

Comment: @Varagian, приходите еще. И на будущее - эта информация должна была быть уже в вопросе, чтобы не приходилось у вас ее выпытывать. Вопрос должен содержать хотя бы маленький кусочек кода, по которому можно было бы сделать хоть какой-то диагноз.